# Swift: is it okay to add constraints to UICollectionview?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this class

```
class HomePage: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate
```

And in this class i have a lot of UIViews.One of which is `tabView`.Now i want to add my `collectionView` to the bottom of `tabView`,how can i do that? Here is my `collectionView

```
    var flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:500,width:self.view.frame.size.width,height:100   ), collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .red`
```

And constraints to `tabView`

```
    tabView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileInfWrapper.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tabView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tabView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/4).isActive = true
    tabView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
```

Comment: have you faced any problem after running it.

Comment: @KrishnarjunBanoth After this code no,but i haven't tried adding anchors.I wanted to know if it's ok to add them to uicollectionview.

Comment: Yes its perfectly ok to add constraints to collectionView

Comment: @user1000 okay thanks

Comment: Please ask for a solution of your problem, dont just ask the question regarding the functionality you want to develop.

Comment: You can set topanchor of collection to be equal to bottom anchor of tabview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the collectionView inside tabView and setup constraints:

```
collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tabView.addSubview(collectionView)

collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

.... And add other constraints

Or you can add it under tab view like so:

```
self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
```

__

BTW you can set tabView's width like so:

```
tabView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.25).isActive = true
```